# Multi select list jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created a multi-select list, but the issue is it doesn't recompose right away (the checkmark doesn't show immediately, I have to scroll down then up for it to appear).
Here is my current code:

Data class:

```kotlin
data class Item(
val obj: SomeObject? = null,
var isSelected: Boolean = false
)
```

ViewModel:

```kotlin
private val _itemsList: MutableStateFlow<MutableList<Item>> = MutableStateFlow(mutableListOf())
val itemsList = _itemsList.asStateFlow()
fun updateSelection(item: Item) {
    _itemsList.value.find {
          it.obj?.id == item.obj?.id
    }?.isSelected = item.isSelected
}
```

Composable functions:

```kotlin
                 Row(
                        modifier = modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .clickable {
                                item.isSelected = !item.isSelected
                                onCheckClicked(item)
                            }
                    ) {
                        CheckableCard(
                            // other unrelated params,
                            isSelected = item.isSelected,
                            onCheckClicked = null
                        )
                    }
                }
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CheckableCard(
    // unrelated params,
    isSelected: Boolean,
    onCheckClicked: ((Boolean) -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    val checkedState by remember { mutableStateOf(isSelected) }

    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(top = 16.dp),
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
        ) {
            // unrelated content
                
            Checkbox(
                checked = checkedState,
                onCheckedChange = onCheckClicked
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I added the onCheckClicked in the Row instead of passing it to the CheckableCard because this way the item's isSelected gets updated correctly when checking/unchecking the item. However this isn't the case when I pass the function to CheckableCard (I'm monitoring the behaviour via log.D and when the function is passed to CheckableCard nothing gets updated)

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

1. Your Row with the clickable, you can use the modifier `toggleable` instead of clickable. With that, you can set the checkbox onCheckedChange to null.
2. Item.isSelected is not a state. So it won't trigger a recomposition. Your updateSelection is just changing that variable and won't update the list. You can try using a MutableStateList, copy the list with the update (might be expensive), or make isSelected a mutable state (might not work for some architectures)
3. You shouldn't have a state in your checkablecard. You are passing in isSelected. That should be set right in the Checkbox

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CheckableCard(
    // unrelated params,
    isSelected: Boolean,
) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(top = 16.dp),
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
        ) {
            // unrelated content
                
            Checkbox(
                checked = isSelected,
                onCheckedChange = null
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You manage composable state wrong.

```
data class Item(
   val obj: SomeObject? = null,
   val isSelected: Boolean = false
)

fun updateSelection(item: Item) {
   _itemsList.value = _itemsList.value?.map {
        if (it.obj?.id == item.obj?.id)
            it.copy(isSelected = !item.isSelected)
        else
            it
    }
}

Row(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable {
            onCheckClicked(item)
        }
) {
    CheckableCard(
        // other unrelated params,
        isSelected = item.isSelected,
    )
}

@Composable
fun CheckableCard(
    // unrelated params,
    isSelected: Boolean,
) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(top = 16.dp),
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
        ) {
            // unrelated content
                
            Checkbox(
                checked = isSelected,
                onCheckedChange = {}
            )
        }
    }
}
```